# Identify which DLL is missing in Jupyter import declaration

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, jupyter

Only when run in Jupyter, scikit learn throws an error saying it cannot find a DLL. There are several answers to this question in SO, none worked for me, but in most cases the solution was to copy the DLL manually. How can I tell from the stack trace below which DLL is missing?

I use Miniconda 3 to install libraries and scikit learn works perfectly in PyCharm IDE.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-019d114f89a0> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     74 else:
     75     from . import __check_build
---> 76     from .base import clone
     77     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     78 

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
     14 
     15 from . import __version__
---> 16 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     17 
     18 _DEFAULT_TAGS = {

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     18 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning
     19 from .deprecation import deprecated
---> 20 from .validation import (as_float_array,
     21                          assert_all_finite,
     22                          check_random_state, column_or_1d, check_array,

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in <module>
     19 from numpy.core.numeric import ComplexWarning
     20 
---> 21 from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan
     22 from .. import get_config as _get_config
     23 from ..exceptions import NonBLASDotWarning

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>
     16 import scipy.sparse as sp
     17 import scipy
---> 18 from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
     19 
     20 

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py in <module>
    114 from .dsolve import *
    115 from .interface import *
--> 116 from .eigen import *
    117 from .matfuncs import *
    118 from ._onenormest import *

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py in <module>
      9 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     10 
---> 11 from .arpack import *
     12 from .lobpcg import *
     13 

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py in <module>
     20 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     21 
---> 22 from .arpack import *

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py in <module>
     43 __all__ = ['eigs', 'eigsh', 'svds', 'ArpackError', 'ArpackNoConvergence']
     44 
---> 45 from . import _arpack
     46 import numpy as np
     47 import warnings

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: Looks like the `scipy` installation is incomplete.  `arpack` refers to one of the fast compiled math libraries.  This is a `(mini)conda` issue, not a `jupyter` one.

Comment: Yes, when I import from `scipy` I get the same error, not only from `sklearn`. I tried `conda install scipy --force-reinstall` but problem persists. Also googled `arpack DLL not found` to see if I can copy the DLL from somewhere but I didn't have luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you are installing the packages to miniconda's base environment?  Try to create a new environment instead.  `conda create -n learn python scipy jupyter`, then activate the environment and see if you get the same error.  `conda activate learn`.

Comment: Recreating everything in a new environment `base2` instead of using `base` solved the problem. This is what I have in my Windows path: `C:\users\pgx\miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\pgx\Miniconda3\envs\base2;C:\Users\pgx\Miniconda3\envs\base2\Scripts;C:\users\pgx\miniconda3;C:\users\pgsch\miniconda3\Scripts`. I have first the new environment `base2` folders, then the default miniconda folders, not sure if this is the right way to go.

Comment: I run the line  `from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier`, and find the `scipy\extra-dll\lib_arpack-.3EACCC44R6URYOMHQMYVCKQCOM2QIBWU.gfortran-win_amd64.dll` is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to stack trace, encapsulate your entire code with try except block. Code below prints out the script name, line number of the error code and type of error. **str(e)** allows a deeper dive into tracing of the stack.

```
import os, sys

try: 
    # Place your code here

except Exception as e:  
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    print("Exception occurred while processing: {}, line {}, {}".format(fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno, exc_type))
    print("Exception occurred: "+ str(e))
```